# Why does the auto-refresh feature not work after pressing the back button?

Tags: support, technical

This may be a technical question more than anything, but I've noticed that if I'm sitting on a tag, say `c++` waiting for new questions to come through, I click the question -> for whatever reason decide to go back to the previous page -> the page no longer auto-refreshes with `x new questions with activity` when a new question is posted.

Why?

Comment: You're using Chrome, aren't you?  Chrome always shows you a cached version of the original page at first; the SE servers have no awareness of your cached copy.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Firefox

Comment: Does Firefox show you the page with the material that was there originally, or a fresh, updated page?

Comment: A cached version

Comment: SE has no awareness of your browser displaying that page if Firefox is showing you a cached copy.  The auto-refresh should kick in again after you refresh the page once.